# php mysql ajax jquery error connection

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, hosting

Backstory: I am running a simple jquery ajax script and I am getting a server reset connection error. This happens when I click on the button calling the script but only happens after several clicks.

```
    function Afunction(){
    var user = $("#div1").text();
    var position = $("#div2").text();


    $.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "html",
    data: ({x: user, y: position}),
    }).done(function (data) {
            $("div3").html(data);
        }).fail(function (e) {
            //Error handling
    alert("uh oh a problem");

     });  


     }
```

Problem: This code works several times when calling the php script and passing the data to the div, then the server resets for no apparent reason. The error handler alerts the phrase I assume because it can't contact server and retrieve the php script.

I am using Linux hosting. Called my hosting company for help but they didn't have answer.

Request: Looking for anyone who has had this problem. Is it my hosting company? Sorry this is so broad but I have tested and tested with no luck. Here is what I have attempted:

1. stripped down code to only the above code
2. simplified mysql table
3. reviewed php script...it works
4. called hosting for help...nada
5. changed php version to 5.4
6. Tried all web browsers. same thing happens

   ```
   <?php

   include('connect.php');

   //post the content in the clicked div

   $username= $_POST['x'];
   $position= $_POST['y'];



   $query2= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE t.user_name='$username' AND t.position = '$position'";



   $results = mysql_query($query2)or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<table class="">

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
      $holder = $row['row'];



    echo '<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
         onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" 
         onMouseDown="">';
    echo '<td style="width: 70%;" >' . $holder . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="width: 15%;" >' . $holder . '</td>';
    echo '<td style="width: 15%;" >' . $holder . '</td>';



    echo "</tr>";

   }
   echo "</table>";



   mysql_close($connect);
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Can we see the relevant PHP?

Comment: What does your browser's developer panel show for the network connection?

Comment: .."then the server **resets**" ... ??? Like, total reset and reboot?

Comment: yes...when I reload the page an error page shows. I also can't upload from dreamweaver. says server not available.

Comment: I'm curious if the fact that his jquery doesn't have `#`s in it is causing this and he's just passing blank data

Comment: # were left out of question but they are in actual script